# Get Ext JS association, inheritance and store to work

Tags: inheritance, extjs, model, associations, store

This is a simple use case for storing one to many (or even one to one) that has inheritance.  How does Ext JS handle this with it's JSON reader?

The following code provides few pseudo models and data to illustrate the use case:

pseudo code example:

```
Models:

Car {
  model,
  year,
  color
}

Truck extends Car {
  bedLength,
  duality
}

Van extends Car {
  leftSlideDoor,
  rightSlideDoor,
  tailGate
}

CarOwner {
  name,
  cars <Car>
}

Data:

carOwners:

[
{
  name: "Sencha",
  cars: [
   {
    color: "Brown",
    model: "Mater"
    type: "truck",
    duality: "false",
    bedLength: "10"
    },
    {
    color: "red",
    model: "sienna",
    type: "van",
    tailGate: "true",
    leftSlideDoor: "true",
    rightSlideDoor: "true"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

When the data is loaded, a "correct" type of Cars are instantiated and loaded.
How can this be done in Ext JS?

Answer (score 0):

From an OO perspective what you've described doesn't work. Your car owner has a collection of 'cars' but the types you are trying to use in your data are not cars, they extend cars. In c# your `carOwner` might contain `List<ICar>` and whilst that would enable you to store trucks and vans, but you'd only be able to use the properties of the ICar interface (as those are the only shared properties).

I would suggest in that example that if the properties are variable you either setup you car own like this:

```
CarOwner {
  name,
  cars <Car>
  vans <Van>
  trucks <Trucks>
}
```

Or you could describe your data as 'Vehicles' and make that object generic enough to  include all the possible properties.

As a side note, if you were purely after en example of a 'association' in Ext and the car/van/truck thing was hypothetical, reply to this and I'll drop one over.